# Support Multiple featured images

Tags: theme-development, metabox, customization

I've created a WordPress theme where in one of my pages I need to use two feature images, I know already how to add support for the featured image and I'm using it.

My need is how to add a second featured image support for my theme WITHOUT using any plugin?

Thanks for any hint, support :)

Comment: Have one image as featured image and add another with postmeta

Comment: Yeah, this is the work-around solution I came up with, but thinking about my client, I don't want to confuse them with different settings

Comment: Just resemble the »featured image«-metabox, right? Name it »second festured image«, I don't see how this can be confusing. Take a look at these sources on here: [one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/38257/22534), [two](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/33173/22534) and [three](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45715/upload-multiple-images-in-a-custom-metabox/45716#45716).